# Connecting Synology NAS Directly to Ubuntu Machine via Ethernet

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, nas

**UPDATE 1/27/2024: I thought I had it working with having DHCP enabled on the NAS but this actually caused problems in my network due to there now being two DHCP servers. So I can't have DHCP enabled on the NAS and I'm back to square one with this setup. :(**

As the title says, I have a headless Ubuntu machine (a Dell OptiPlex 7050 running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Desktop) that is connected to my network as well as a Synology DS916+ also connected to my network.

Both machines run completely fine and I can connect to them both from my Windows machine without any issue. All machines have dedicated IPs set via my Asus Router.

The Ubuntu machine is basically a fresh install with very little configuration done on it so far. I have xrdp installed on it so I can remote into it via my Windows machine. I also have the SSH server enabled so that I can access it via a terminal as well.

The DS916+ has two ethernet ports. LAN 1 connects it to my router/network and is working normally. LAN 2 is connected to a USB to Ethernet adapter to the Ubuntu Machine.

I have Samba set up on the NAS and am able to connect to it via the Windows machine as well as the Ubuntu machine (however only using LAN 1 so via the network)

So basically I'm trying to get the headless Ubuntu machine to connect to the NAS directly via a private network.

The NAS says LAN 2 is connected, however the Ubuntu machine stays on "Connecting..." until it ultimately fails with a "Activation of network failed" message.

I was mainly using this YouTube video as a resource: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQITnitG9_E but also tried some things from other forums and resources and nothing seems to work.

I've attached some screenshots of the current configuration of the network settings on both the NAS and the Ubuntu machine but I've also tried the "Link-Local Only" setting on the Ubuntu machine and get the same results every time no matter what I do.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Isn't it the case that a Synology NAS itself is a headless server and that you usually connect to the NAS via a Windoze or Linux client? Are you addressing this issur from the correct angle?

Comment: @graham The NAS itself is a headless server however it doesn't have the resources to do what I want it to do (Plex server, 4k streaming) which is where the OptiPlex comes into play. I'm just wanting to use the NAS as storage.

Comment: There are a number of resources available in regard to using Synology as a Plex server - [here is one](https://forums.plex.tv/t/installation-setup-of-plex-media-server-on-synology/572179) I found without much trouble and there are plenty of other references.

Comment: @graham Yes, I know how to turn a Synology NAS into a Plex server. That is not what I'm asking here. I simply want to connect my Synology NAS directly to my Dell/Ubuntu machine via ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

A crossover cable is the most appropriate cable to use in connecting two computers because it allows for direct communication between the two devices without the need for a network switch or hub. This type of cable is specifically designed to connect similar devices, such as two computers or two switches, by crossing over the transmit and receive lines to ensure that the devices can communicate effectively. In contrast, a regular Ethernet cable, also known as a straight-through cable, is used to connect different types of devices, such as a computer to a network switch or router.

Comment: @supi007 I'm not using a crossover cable, just a regular ethernet cable. Would that really cause the Ubuntu machine to not successfully connect to the NAS?

Comment: From standard perspective it would. In the past it was a real showstopper if you wanted to connect two computers to each other. Nowadays it has been handled by the network cards. Crossover cable is not necesserally needed to be used anymore. I saw your figured out. Ubuntu showed on the GUI you have IP address but in reality you hadn't. May I delete my Answer ?

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE 1/27/2024: This actually caused problems in my network due to there now being two DHCP servers. So I can't have DHCP enabled on the NAS and I'm back to square one with this setup. :(**

I figured it out!

So I ran this on the Ubuntu machine:

```
sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager
```

and saw the following messages whenever the connection failed:

```
state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 2'
```

after doing some research this led me to believe that the Ubuntu machine was having issues configuring it's static IP which made me think, "One of these machines need to act as a DHCP server to assign IP addresses right?"

So I basically followed this YouTube video exactly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiZXDWKOgEA to get my Synology NAS to act as a DHCP server on LAN 2.

I then configured a static IP for LAN 2 on my NAS based on the information I set up for the DHCP server <s>and set the Ubuntu machine to automatically get it's IP from the NAS (non-static, I don't need the Ubuntu machine to have a static IP on this network, only the NAS)</s> *(I did end up setting a static IP for the Ubuntu machine, see update at the bottom of this post*) and boom, it connected and I'm able to access the NAS's interface via the static IP on LAN 2 from the Ubuntu machine.

I've attached some screenshots of the configuration that ended up working on between both machines:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE: I did end up configuring the Ubuntu machine to also have a static IP address so that I could set up NFS permissions on the NAS to only allow connections from the Ubuntu machine without the need for a password so that it could auto-mount via fstab.**